# Json decode taking away string quotes

Tags: php, json, slim

I have the following JSON:

```
{"name":"Hello World","products":[{"name":"cup","type":"large"},{"name":"spoon","type":"small"}]}
```

I'm using a curl request and Slim to get:

```
$vars = json_decode($app->request->getBody(), true);
print_r($vars);
```

But it takes away the quotes for the `name` and `type`, so when I try to use a foreach loop on them, it doesn't think they are strings.

```
Array
(
  [name] => Hello World
  [products] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => cup
                [type] => large
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => spoon
                [type] => small
            )

    )

)
```

When I use a foreach like this:

```
foreach ($vars as $var){
   print_r($var);
   echo $var[0]['name'];
}
```

I get the error: `Illegal string offset 'name'`
Why is this occurring? Thanks for all help!

Comment: That is... correct. Why do you think it's not? "so when I try to use a foreach loop on them, it doesn't think they are strings." - wait, what? What is your foreach loop?

Comment: use `var_dump` and you'll see them in quotes

Comment: It sounds like the real issue is to do with your `foreach` loop. Perhaps show that bit of code?

Comment: `print_r` doesn't show string delimiters (quotation marks).

Comment: As for your `for` loop - you're trying to iterate over an array with two keys - `name` and `product`. One value is a string, one is numeric array. Neither has a `name` key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I get the error: Illegal string offset 'name' Why is this occurring?

Because the first element you are iterating over is `$vars['name']`, which has the value `'Hello World'`, which is a string. And `'Hello World'['name']` just doesn't work.

Looks like you want to iterate over `$vars['products']` only.

Comment: I believe this qualifies the question as "too localised" (now named typo/not reproducible), doesn't it?

Comment: You are right. I wish was "too localized" back.

Answer (score 3):

You're looping the outer loop. Looks like you want to loop products only.

```
foreach ($vars['products'] as $var) {
   echo $var['name'];
}
```